# Retrieve previously paired bluetooth device lists

Tags: ios, objective-c, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

Is there any way to retrieve paired bluetooth device list on iOS without given UDID? Ex: I'have connected sound-stick, car sound system etc.. I would like to retrieve these device names...

Regards.

Comment: No, there is no API for this. Further, you can only discover BLE peripherals, not legacy peripherals such as speakers, handsfree etc

Comment: if you want to track perviously connected peripherals than you have take a reference of connected device info in you local storage .